# How can I get lightbox to find the data-lightbox-attribute within an SVG Link?

Tags: svg, attributes, lightbox, xlink

Up to now I use lightbox together with an Imagemap to link between a person on a group-image to a lightbox-popup with details about this person. I use the data-lightbox-attribute in the link to transport the data. To get the website responsible, I try to use a linked image in a svg with polygon shapes around the target-person. I tried to use xlink:data-lightbox="Data to be shown" to help lightbox to find my Data - no success.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 750 429">
<image width="750" height="429" xlink:href="images/Groupimage.jpg">
</image>
<a xlink:href="images/image1.jpg" xlink:title="A Name" xlink:data-lightbox="lightbox-partner"  xlink:data-title="<h3>A Name</h3>
>
<g id="Name">
    <polygon class="st0" opacity="0" points="209,429 31,429 8,327.3 43,154.3 115.1,127.1 113,50.3 156.6,28.5 189,51.3 183,131.3 209,172.3 253,276.3 341,299.3 341,333.3 197,317."/>
 </g></a>
 </svg>
```

When I click the image I get only the linked image in the window. No lightbox.
I am not a coder. I try around but don't realy know what i'm doing ...
Thanks for a kick in the right direktion!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake!
I thought the Link within the svg has to be a "xlink:href" becouse of  the XLink-namespace not a "href". But the link in the svg works without the prefix "xlink", and without the "xlink:href" lightbox can find the following "data-lightbox-attribute".
Problem solved! No more unresponsible imagemaps!

Sorry for my bad english ...